# how to add text with spaces to label using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, text, set, label

I am using the following code to set label's text using jquery which is working fine but when the string contains space then it shows "%" on the place of space:

```
function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

function setText() {
        $('[id$=lblQuestionText]').html(getUrlVars()["data"]);
    }
```

**when the string contains space like "This is text" then it shows output like "this%is%text"**

I have already tried ".text()" and ".html()" but none of them worked for me, please help me how can show the string as it comes with spaces.

Comment: What about using a simpler selector istead of this fancy awfulness ? I'd bet my hand your selector is wrong.

Comment: @Virus721 What's wrong with the selector?

Comment: You are using text from URLs... Spaces are encoded as %20 or in this case it appears simply % (odd!)... a string replace will fix that, else use a decoding component

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xDUUg/354/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `decodeURIComponent()` function:

change this:

```
return vars;
```

to this with `decodeURIComponent()` function:

```
return decodeURIComponent(vars);
```

Comment: the concept you have used it not worked but when i used it as "$('[id$=lblQuestionText]').html(decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["data"]));"  it works for me

Answer (score 0):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/WEkrt/

You can also use a global replace match to convert the % to spaces if you do not want to decode the entire URL.

```
var text = "this%is%text";
text = text.replace(/\%/g, ' ')
$('[id$=lblQuestionText]').text(text);
```

or in your specific case:

$('[id$=lblQuestionText]').text(getUrlVars()["data"].replace(/\%/g, ' '));

Answer (score -2):

You should try with  `innerHTML` instead of `html` and `text`

Comment: innerHTML is not a JQuery method. He may have meant the element method, e.g. $('[id$=lblQuestionText]')[0].innerHTML, but that does not work either.